# Do I need any additional Java packages if I'm running the Oracle JRE?

Tags: java, openjdk, oracle

I am running the Java 7 JRE from Oracle. I installed it through terminal and it works properly with my web browsers, and otherwise, as far as I can tell.

However, I was browsing through my installed packages in Software Center, and noticed that both the [openjdk-7-jre-lib [image: Install openjdk-7-jre-lib]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-7-jre-lib) and [openjdk-7-jre-headless [image: Install openjdk-7-jre-headless]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-7-jre-headless) packages were still installed from when I had the OpenJKD JRE installed, which I have since uninstalled, but did use for a good period of time before I switched.

Should those be there, or might they cause complications if I leave them installed? Or would it be best to leave them installed?

Answer (score 0):

It won't do any harm if you leave them installed. If you do decide to uninstall them (because I don't think they're needed since you're using Oracle's JRE), make sure it does not offer to uninstall other important packages with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove OpenJDK JRE without any problem or leave it just the same.

Java is a technology from Oracle (formerly: Sun Microsystems). There are several implementations:

1. OpenJDK: The primary goal of the OpenJDK project is to produce an
   open-source implementation of the Java SE Platform (6 and 7). This
   is the default version of Java that Ubuntu uses and is the easiest
   to install.
2. Oracle (Sun) Java 6: Oracle (Sun) Java 6 is the reference implementation for Java 6.
3. Oracle Java 7: Oracle Java 7 is the reference implementation for Java 7.
4. IBM Java: IBM Java is the preferred Java solution on PowerPC machines. It is a reimplementation with a Just-In-Time Compiler. It is only available from IBM's website.

To manage your Java version/flavour in terminal use `update-alternatives`, to list the available java versions `update-alternatives --list java`.

If you'd wish all could be installed without issues, and you could choose witch one to use using `update-alternatives --config java**`

Please take note that java as four components, they must all be configured to you preference.

1. `java` Java Runtime Environment (JRE);
2. `javaws` Java Web Start, Java application over the net;
3. `javac` Java Compiler, JDK for Developers;
4. And of course the browser plugin, currently mine is `libnpjp2.so` with `firefox` is easy to find out yours just type `about:plugins` in the address bar.

Normally the several java flavors/versions are in `/usr/lib/jvm`, me, for example have OpenJDK and two different versions of Oracle-Java.